# I am trying to create a database with flask_sqlalchemy in python and it not showing up

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Hi all I am trying to make a database in python using flask and flask_sqlalchemy there is no error when I run the code but there is no database been created as far as I can see, i am sure it is just something silly, thank you so much in advance, i have been trying to complete this most of today, i am dyslexic as well so it might be just something that is not in the correct place

```
import os


from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, SelectField, RadioField, HiddenField, StringField, IntegerField, FloatField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, Regexp, NumberRange
from datetime import date


app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '**'

# Flask-Bootstrap requires this line
Bootstrap(app)

# the name of the database; add path if necessary
db_name = 'test.db'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + db_name

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True


db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class clients(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Clients'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    dateentred = db.Column(db.String)
    business = db.Column(db.String)
    fname = db.Column(db.String)
    mname = db.Column(db.String)
    sname = db.Column(db.String)
    address = db.Column(db.String)
    town = db.Column(db.String)
    postcode = db.Column(db.String)
    molbphone = db.Column(db.Integer)
    landline = db.Column(db.Float)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    lastupdate = db.Column(db.String)
    active = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, dateentred, business, fname, mname, sname, address, town, postcode, molbphone,landline ,email ,lastupdate,active):
        self.dateentred = dateentred
        self.business = business
        self.fname = fname
        self.mname = mname
        self.sname = sname
        self.address = address
        self.town = town
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.molbphone = molbphone
        self.landline = landline
        self.email = email
        self.lastupdate = lastupdate
        self.active = active

    class AddRecord(FlaskForm):
        id_field = HiddenField()
        dateentred = StringField('Date of record Entry')
        business = StringField('Name of business')
        fname = SelectField('First name of the client')
        mname = StringField('Middle name of the client')
        sname = StringField('Last name of the client')
        address = StringField('Street address of the client')
        town = StringField('Town or City name of for the client')
        postcode = StringField('The postcode for the client')
        molbphone = StringField('This is the molbphone number for the client')
        landline = StringField('This is the landline for the client')
        email = StringField('This is the email for the client')
        lastupdate = StringField(' This was the last time the file was updated ')
        active = StringField('This is to let us know if the client is active ')
        # updated - date - handled in the route function
        updated = HiddenField()
        submit = SubmitField('Add/Update Record')

    db.create_all()
    print(u"current directory: %s" % os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open `flask shell`, `import db`  and run `db.create_all()`

Comment: i added db.create_all() to the end of the code and when i added import DB it said i already had it , it made a BD but its empty

Comment: I updated the code at the top with my changes

Comment: please show the screenshot

Comment: If it says that the db is empty and you can see `test.db` then that is fine, you just have to add stuff to it

Comment: thanks for the comment, i mean when i open the database there is no tbaes listed

Comment: open the database with sqlite and type `. tables` tell me what it shows

Comment: hey mate why did you vote me down i researched this before i asked , also there ws no tables when in sqllitestudio

Comment: I did not do that

Comment: no issues mate  can you help me at all to fix this

Comment: please open sqlite, do a `. tables` and send screenshot

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could use the `app_context`

```py
def create_app():
    app =  Flask(__name__)
    ....
    with app.app_context():
         db.create_all()
         db.session.commit()
    ....
```